# undefined method `path' in httmultiparty and how can I fix that

Tags: ruby, soundcloud

I use the ruby soundcloud gem, but I run into an issue from httmultiparty which is known.

So the related issues on github are https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby/issues/20 and https://github.com/jwagener/httmultiparty/issues/19.

As I understand the error this methode does something wrong:

```
def self.flatten_params(params={}, prefix='')
  flattened = []
  params.each do |(k,v)|
    if params.is_a?(Array)
      v = k
      k = ""
    end

    flattened_key = prefix == "" ? "#{k}" : "#{prefix}[#{k}]"
    if v.is_a?(Hash) || v.is_a?(Array)
      flattened += flatten_params(v, flattened_key)
    else
      flattened << [flattened_key, v]
    end
  end
  flattened
end
```

My problem is I'm not so expert so understand what's wrong and how I can fix that.
So can anyone explain how I can fix that or is there at least a workaround?